# How to enter excel columns into array and compare the two arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vbscript

The code below won't write anything to the text file and comes up with no error. I'm trying to take a column of excel data and put into an array. Then take another column of data and put it into an array. The first column contains names and the 2nd column contains values. I'm trying to take all the names that match and see if the values match as well.

example:

Column 1:.....................................................................................Column 2:

```
John                                              1/2/2013
John                                              1/2/2013
George                                            1/2/2013
George                                            7/14/2013
George                                            6/2/2013
Connor                                            5/1/2013
Connor                                            5/1/2013
Connor                                            6/19/2013
```

The output I wanted to write to a text file was:

```
John                                              1/2/2013
John                                              1/2/2013
Connor                                            5/1/2013
Connor                                            5/1/2013
```

Code I have so far:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim Appx, Bookx, shiftx 
Dim filename, value1, value2, value3, value4

filename = "c:\finRate.xls"

Set Appx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set Bookx = Appx.WorkBooks.Open(filename)
set shiftx = Appx.activesheet

value1 = shiftx.Cells(2, 1)
value2 = shiftx.Cells(2, 2)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5000").FormulaArray = value3
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5000").FormulaArray = value4

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\predata1.txt", ForReading)
objFile.writeline value3
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\predata2.txt", ForReading)
objFile.writeline value4
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\Noduplicates.txt", 2, True)
Set objOutputFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\Duplicates.txt", 2, True)
Set objOutputFile3 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\alone.txt", 2, True)
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


xlBook.Close False
Appx.Quit


set shiftx = Nothing
Set Bookx = Nothing
Set Appx = Nothing 


Do until objFile.atEndOfStream
    strCurrentLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If not Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) then 
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        Dict.Add strCurrentLine,strCurrentLine
    ElseIf Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) then 
        objOutputFile2.WriteLine strCurrentLine

    Else
        objOutputFile3.WriteLine strCurrentLine
    End if 
Loop
wscript.echo "Finished"
```

Comment: Very thought detailed question nice job.

Comment: If I understand it right, there look to be a few issues with the code.  But the one that you are probably stuck on is that `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5000").FormulaArray = value3` means "take value3 (which at that point contains null) and write it to the array formula in each cell of the range".  That is probably the opposite of what you intend.  Try `value3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5000").Value` and similar for the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually need all duplicate lines, or would a list of unique duplicates suffice? The latter could be achieved with an [ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) [query](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_databases_excel.php) against the worksheet:

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.xlsx"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filename & _
          ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;"""

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT [Name],[Date] FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "GROUP BY [Name],[Date] HAVING Count([Name]) > 1"

Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields(0).Value & vbTab & rs.Fields(1).Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
conn.Close
```

Adjust the name of the sheet and the column headers as required.

Note that on 64-bit systems you need to run this code with a 32-bit VBScript interpreter (from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`).